# On Linux, how do I run a GUI app from a terminal shell under a different login?

Tags: linux, permissions, x11

Here's the deal. I logged into a Linux box (CentOS, but that shouldn't matter)
as user A. I had to build a program as user B, so I started up a terminal
shell, logged into that shell as B, and built it. When I try to run the app,
I get this message:

"connect to ":0.0" refused by server"

Most likely because the current X Windows session is owned by user A, and as
B, I don't have permissions to access A's stuff.

Is there a correct way to solve this. Any incorrect ways?

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `ssh -Y ...` worked as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you logged in, but if it was something like this:

```
sudo -i userB
```

the DISPLAY and TERM variables are left unchanged, and you may need to set them.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssh -X userb@localhost
```

(and someone with more rep than me should move this to SU)

Answer (score 0):

`xhost +localhost` opens your box to allow all users on your box to run their X software on your screen. Obviously, this also allows for practical jokes from other users.

Comment: Hah, I was faster by 21 seconds!

Comment: TBH: congrats, missed that :-))

Answer (score -1):

```
xhost +
```

From user who ran X server.